# MinGW compilation for the Orange Book source code

Tags: opengl, mingw

I am trying to get the right setup for MinGW for OpenGL.

What must I do to get MinGW to compile the code below under a Windows system?:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// triangles.cpp
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };

GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint  NumVertices = 6;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//

void 
init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);

    GLfloat  vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        { -0.90, -0.90 },  // Triangle 1
        {  0.85, -0.90 },
        { -0.90,  0.85 },
        {  0.90, -0.85 },  // Triangle 2
        {  0.90,  0.90 },
        { -0.85,  0.90 }
    };

    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
                 vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderInfo  shaders[] = {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//

void 
display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);

    glFlush();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//

int 
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     glutInit(&argc, argv);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
     glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
     glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
     glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
     glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

     if (glewInit()) {
         cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     init();

     glutDisplayFunc(display);

     glutMainLoop();
}
```

To avoid more code clogging I haven't posted the include headers but they can be viewed at the website: http://www.opengl-redbook.com/.

As for my attempts of setting it up myself I have:
downloaded Glut and extracted the folder to a file directory of: C:\freeglut\
downloaded Glew and extracted its include folder and lib folder to C:\freeglut\include\ and C:\freeglut\lib\ respectively
I followed this by using the following makefile:

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = triangles.cpp

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = triangles

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I"C:\freeglut\include

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib"

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lfreeGLUT -lOpenGL32 -lglu32 -lglew32

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

Which to no surprise after hours of tinkering, adjusting, readjusting lead to a long fat list of cease and desist undefined references to various __glut functions.

Any MinGW alternate configurations, advice, or help?

Comment: Are you able to compile toy programs with your MinGW installation?

Comment: If you mean programs that aren't OpenGL specific, yes. If you mean OpenGL programs then no. I was able to at first compile a glut program but it was very basic and straight GLUT with no glew. If you need more confirmation on the toy programs I can run please send me a link to the source that you would consider a toy program.